# how to protect website from sql injection and hacking etc

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have create a small social network with eCommerce and blog etc. I have create the site with PHP and JavaScript. Fully hand code and no plugin. I didn't upload it because of security. This is my first website and I have also create the database. Now my question is what is the security I have to look and How to protect from all kind of attacks?
If there is any tutorial or book for it, give me this link.

Comment: google.com, sorry, but there are so many tutorials, books and information about this topic that I can't even begin to believe you have even tried looking for it.

Comment: This is a question that has already been asked too many times... e.g. /questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: meewok - your link is not opening

Comment: It's the top link over in the **Related** sidebar.

Comment: Oops:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Thank you very much all of you.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL injection, use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) properly and hacking is a very broad topic and there are tons of ways to hack a website. Check out [OWASP](http://owasp.com).

And if it's your first website, I don't recommend using it as a real eCommerce website because you have a hell of a lot to loose if you get hacked.

Comment: Also look into a paypal plugin, and then you wont really have to worry too much about getting your bank account hacked... paypal will secure the plugin for you

Comment: That first sentence really doesn't make sense: "Use PDO properly and for hacking"... what?

Comment: I mean something like "binding parameters" instead of using PDO like this **$stmt = pdo->query("SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE userId={$_POST['id']}");** Oh... and I am making an edit. I see what you mean.

Comment: Thank you guys. I would like to use paypal but they charge for transaction

Comment: Really? Oh, i didnt notice that, sorry!